# Extracting hyperspectral pixel values to shapefile?

Tags: python, raster, hyperspectral-sensor

I have developed a workflow for a question that might have an easier answer.

Say you have a hyperspectral image and a set of polygons overlapping the image. I want to extract all pixel values that fall in the polygons, such that the final dataset has n columns for n bands (with each observation being the pixel value for that band).

In ArcMap it would be the tool 'Extract Multi Value From Point', but is there a similar tool in GDAL?

My current workflow is as follows:

1. Load the hyperspectral image
2. Save each band as a separate tif
3. Convert each separate tif to points
4. Spatially join the points to the polygons
5. Rinse and repeat

While this works, it feels horribly inefficient and that I must be missing some multiband raster functionality.

Comment: What file format is the hyperspectral image in?

Comment: You may also be interested in geocube. Here is an example of extracting raster data to polygons: https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/examples/zonal_statistics.html

Comment: HSI image is in .tiff format, but I can convert it to any other format (.las, etc). 
I'll definitely look into the geocube! Main problem seems to be getting it all into a single dataframe - taking a long time 30+ minutes for 50 bands. Likely a leave overnight project.

Comment: Your wording suggests that your polygons cover one pixel exactly. If not, you'd need to aggregate values (e.g. calculate the average of reflectance in each band for every polygon). Can you clarify?